# How to get all .mp3 files from raw folder to custom array listview and play that song?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, audio-player, android-music-player

I am developing one app that can play .mp3 file.So,In this app i have created one custom listview adapter for populating the .mp3 files from raw folder to listview and created one model class and in my raw folder i have 20 .mp3 files.So, I want to add this all raw folder .mp3 files to listview in each row.after that when user click that particular listview item at that time play that song given position.

**Note:** I am not importing that .mp3 files from SDCARD.

**Here this my adapter**

```
public class RingtoneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RingtoneModel> {

private List<RingtoneModel> planetList;
private Context context;


public RingtoneAdapter(List<RingtoneModel> planetList, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.ringtone_row_layout, planetList);
    this.planetList = planetList;
    this.context = ctx;
}

public int getCount() {
    return planetList.size();
}

public RingtoneModel getItem(int position) {
    return planetList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return planetList.get(position).hashCode();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();


    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ringtone_row_layout, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

        holder.planetNameView = tv;

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else 
        holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();

    RingtoneModel p = planetList.get(position);
    holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());


    return v;
}


private static class PlanetHolder {
    public TextView planetNameView;
}


}
```

**This my model class**

```
public class RingtoneModel {

private String name;
private Integer distance;
private String descr;
private int idImg;

public RingtoneModel(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

public RingtoneModel(String name, String descr) {
    this.name = name;
    this.descr = descr;
}

public RingtoneModel(String name, Integer distance, String descr, int idImg) {
    this.name = name;
    this.descr = descr;
    this.idImg = idImg;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}
public int getIdImg() {
    return idImg;
}
public void setIdImg(int idImg) {
    this.idImg = idImg;
}
}
```

**And this is my MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


List<RingtoneModel> ringtoneList = new ArrayList<RingtoneModel>();
RingtoneAdapter ringAdapter;
ListView ringtoneListMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    initRingtoneList();

    ringtoneListMain = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.rintoneList);

    ringAdapter = new RingtoneAdapter(ringtoneList,this);

    ringtoneListMain.setAdapter(ringAdapter);

    ringtoneListMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

private void initRingtoneList() {

    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("xyz"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Venus"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Mars"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Jupiter"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Saturn"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Uranus"));
    ringtoneList.add(new RingtoneModel("Neptune"));
}
}
```

So,If anyone know how i can do all this then please help me...

Answer (score 1):

First get the item index in the ListView when users click a button in ListView.

```
    View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
    ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
    final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
```

After you got the exact position index, find the English word audio file and create an URI for that audio file.

```
Uri mp3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
          + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/"
          + datas.get(position).word);
```

After you have the audio file URI, you can instantiate the MediaPlayer class and play the audio file in Android.

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, mp3);
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
```

When the music stops, release the MediaPlayer instance immediately so that it will not consume lot of resources.

```
 private OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
};
```