# How to put all mp3 files from raw folder into a list by name and other metadata?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that can play MP3 files. I want to convert mp3 files inside the raw folder into an ArrayList of song objects, using the mp3 file's name as its title. Here's my code. I've taken it from this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195749/how-to-get-all-mp3-files-from-raw-folder-to-custom-array-listview-and-play-that) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
public void getSongList() {
    try {
        Log.d("Test", "reached");
        Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getDeclaredFields();

        Log.d("Test", "reached2");
        for (Field f : fields) {
            allSongs.addSong(new Song(0, f.getName(), ""));
        }
        Log.d("Test", "reached3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Test", "reached4");
        Log.d("Test", allSongs.getSongs().size() + "");
        Log.d("Test", e.toString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
07-03 15:50:52.497 17106-17106/poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp D/Test: reached
07-03 15:50:52.497 17106-17106/poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp D/Test: reached2
07-03 15:50:52.498 17106-17106/poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp D/Test: reached4
07-03 15:50:52.498 17106-17106/poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp D/Test: 0
07-03 15:50:52.498 17106-17106/poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp D/Test: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp.AllSongs.addSong(poc.cevt.hmi.com.musicplayerapp.Song)' on a null object reference
```

I have one mp3 file inside my raw folder. The Song's first and third parameters are ID and artist respectively, I'm just trying to get the title to work for now. Any alternative/better solutions to what I have are also welcome.

Comment: "which means it's throwing an exception but I don't understand why" -- you are printing the stack trace. Take a look at it.

Comment: @CommonsWare There's a null object reference but I don't know why, because my raw folder isn't empty

Comment: You might consider editing your question and posting the complete Java stack trace, so everybody else can see it.

Comment: I've added them

Comment: Note that your edit does not contain a Java stack trace, but rather only the error message. In this case, that was sufficient, but in the future, post the entire Java stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allSongs` is `null`, and so you are getting a `NullPointerException` on your call to `addSong()`.

Comment: Wow spent hours looking for such a simple bug. Thanks. Relatively new to android studios